# Flex - Changing component states through main

Tags: apache-flex

i'm trying to change components states through a control bar button (id=btn) in main... so i add an event listener to it ... the code goes like this

```
import flash.events.EventDispatcher;
            import flash.events.MouseEvent;
            import mx.core.FlexGlobals;

FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.btn.addEventListener
                (MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, change_state, true, 0, false);

public function change_state(e:MouseEvent):void{this.currentState="wait";}
```

but i get an "1120-access of undefined property change_state" error... can someone help me !?

Comment: I tried something very similar to this code and it appears to be working for me. This appears to be a scope issue, double check them all. Especially when working with states.

Comment: IF you provide more code, it may help. Where are you setting the event listener; and where is your function? If they aren't in the same component, that may cause issues.  Logistically, I would recommend against listening to the topLevelApplication if at all possible, as it violates encapsulation rules.

Comment: thks for the quick answers ... the code i posted is all in the component, and the btn is in the main.mxml where i just call the component, and have that button(btn) in a control bar...  it maybe be a scope issue... i try to create a test project it as no errors ... but the button doesn't change the states..

Comment: `code`<s:Application ...... creationComplete="Handler()"><fx:Script><![CDATA[ import flash.events.EventDispatcher; import flash.events.MouseEvent; public function Handler():void{ btn.addEventListener (MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, change, true, 0, false); } public function change(e:MouseEvent):void{currentState="login";} ]]> </fx:Script> <s:states> <s:State name="adm"/> <s:State name="login"/> </s:states> <s:Button label="Button" id="btn"/> <s:Button label="login" includeIn="login"/> </s:Application>

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling that the underscore in `change_state` is causing issues and I feel there might be a scope issue, when you reference it. Try rewriting your code like this:

```
import flash.events.EventDispatcher;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;             
import mx.core.FlexGlobals;  

FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,this.changeState, true, 0, false);  

public function changeState(e:MouseEvent):void{this.currentState="wait";}
```

Does this make a big difference?